# Find the supremum of the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Hi I'm trying to figure out for which values of $w$  the absolute value of the supremum of $u(x,t)$ is infinity. 
The function $u(x,t)$ is the following. According to my calculation is going to be all the $w=n$ =integer except $4$ and $6$.

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \frac{1}{2\pi} [\frac{\sin(wx)}{n^2-w^2}] [ \frac{\sin(xn-6x)}{n-6} - \frac{\sin(xn-4x)}{n-4}-$$
$$ + \frac{\sin(nx+4x)}{n+4} - \frac{\sin(xn+6x)}{n+6} ] \} \sin(nx) $$

Comment: $w=4$ and $w=6$ are problematic too, because $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x^2}$ does not exist at $x=0$.

Comment: @Nicolas if I exclude this two values then the supremum is going to be infinity?

Comment: If $w$ is not an integer, then your serie is convergent, because this time $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}$ exists at $x=0$ and the serie $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: @Nicolas I found that exactly result, when w is different than n. But I don't know what to do for the case where they are equal

Comment: Your formula does not exist when $w>0$ is integer. But given the other question you've posted about the orthogonality of the functions $\sin\left(n.\right)$ and $\cos\left(n.\right)$, I guess that it is a kind of Fourier serie (a projection on the trigonometric polynomials); if it is, then I suggest you to come back to your original formula and to put $w$ integer : $\frac{\sin\left(wx\right)}{n^2-w^2}$ will be valid only when $w$ is not integer, and the resulting formula will be different otherwise. If I'm wrong, then please post your original formula.